# ¿Cómo recorrer un listado en mPDF?

Tags: php, html, mpdf

Requiero recorrer un `array`de la respectiva consulta que he realizado desde el mismo documento o `script` donde estoy generando el reporte en `PDF`, pero la verdad nunca he implementado `PHP` puro dentro de etiquetas `HTML` por lo que me está dando un poco de lidia tratar de encrustar o pintar los datos en su respectiva columna (procuro usar siempre el modelo Cliente-Servidor) pero en este caso no es posible, dado que todo es generado en la parte del servidor:

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
<table class="table-item table-striped" style="overflow: visible|hidden|wrap">
      <tr class="thead-primary">
        <th scope="col" style="color: #ffffff">#</th>
        <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="color: #ffffff">Código</th>
        <th class="text-left" scope="col" style="color: #ffffff">Producto</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>' .
      while ($row = $consultaDetalleFactura->fetch_assoc())
      {
        $contador++;
        $codigoProducto = $row['codigo_producto'];
        $nombreProducto = $row['nombre_producto'];
        $mpdf .=
        '
        <tr  style="height:500px;">
          <th scope="row">
            ' . $contador . '
          </th>
          <td class="text-left" autosize="1.6">
            ' . $codigoProducto . '
          </td>
          <td class="text-left">
            ' . $nombreProducto . '
          </td>
        </tr>
        '. 
      }
      $mpdf .= '
      </tbody>
    </table>
');
```

Por lo que de esta manera estoy obteniendo un error de sintaxis:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in C:\Users\Johan
>   Corrales\Documents\GitHub\angular\api\Class\PDF2\prueba.php on line
>   407

Gracias!

Comment: Estas intentando concatenar un texto con un while. Eso no tiene sentido y por eso te da ese error.

Comment: Hola @JDev por eso mismo hice referencia en que nunca habia realizado un proceso de estos directamente con PHP. Gracias!